# Assembly 8086 ,range of a 16 bit register and cmp

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, x86-16

I made this procedure which prints a 16 bit number (the range should be 0-65535),
Below is the code, if I replace the line where the problem is(the big HERE in the code) with this `cmp ax,32767` (take the number as a 16 bit presign ) everything works ok but when I have the 65535 as a max it messes up the output(just prints 1 char).

I had the idea that 16 bit registers in assembly can take numbers in the range of 0-(2^16-1),like the 8 bit registers can take in the range 0-(2^8-1)

```
emfanisi_arithmou proc near  ;ax the digit
        cmp ax,10
        jl l101    
        cmp ax,100
        jl l102              
        cmp ax,1000
        jl l103       
        cmp ax,10000
        jl l104     
        cmp ax,65535; <- HERE , HEY HERE DO YOU SEE ME?
        jle l105                  
        l101:
            mov cx,1
            jmp loop105
        l102:
            mov cx,2
            jmp loop105
        l103:
            mov cx,3
            jmp loop105
        l104:
            mov cx,4
            jmp loop105
        l105:
            mov cx,5
        loop105:
            mov dx,0
            mov bx,cx
            dec bx
            shl bx,1  
            mov bx,powerof10[bx]
            div bx
            push dx
            mov dl,al            
            add dl,48
            mov ah,2
            int 21h
            pop ax      
        loop loop105
    ret 
emfanisi_arithmou endp 
powerof10 dw 1,10,100,1000,10000;in the data segment
```

Comment: Look more closely what `jl` means and how it differs from `jb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use `JBE` instead of `JLE`.**

`CMP` sets the status flags as if the second operand were substracted from the first operand.
`JLE` jumps if the *zero flag* is set, or the *sign flag* is different from the *overflow flag*. `JBE` jumps if the *carry flag* is set, or the *zero flag* is set.

As the Intel Instruction Set Reference nicely summarize it:

> The terms “less” and “greater” are used for comparisons of signed
>   integers and the terms “above” and “below” are used for unsigned
>   integers.

Comment: ohh I didnt knew that,does the same apply on 8 bit numbers?

Comment: Yes. Values in CPU registers are not signed or unsigned per se. There are the operations which compute results as if the operands where signed or unsigned (sometimes it is the same operation, thanks to the the two's complement magic).